# The definition of an Ordered pair and Cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> The ordered pair $(a,b)$ is defined to be the set
>    $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$; its first component is $a$ 
>   and its second component is $b$.

$\cdots $

> The Cartesian product of classes $A$ and $B$ is the class $$A \times B = \{ (a,b) \mid a \in A, \; b \in B\}$$

*~ Hungerford's Algebra p.6*

To my understanding, the definition of the Cartesian product is the set of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ with $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. That is, $$A \times B = \{ \{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\} \mid a \in A, \; b \in B\}$$
As an example, let $A = \{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n\}$ and $B = \{b_1, b_2, \cdots , b_m \}$. The following are the ordered pairs that make up $A \times B$: $$(a_1,b_1) = \{ \{a_1\}, \{a_1,b_1\}\}, \;(a_1,b_2) =  \{ \{a_1\}, \{a_1,b_2\}\}, \; \cdots, (a_1, b_m) = \{ \{a_1\}, \{a_1,b_m\}\}$$
$$(a_2,b_1) = \{ \{a_2\}, \{a_2,b_1\}\}, \;(a_2,b_2) =  \{ \{a_2\}, \{a_2,b_2\}\}, \; \cdots, (a_2, b_m) = \{ \{a_2\}, \{a_2,b_m\}\}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$(a_n,b_1) = \{ \{a_n\}, \{a_n,b_1\}\}, \;(a_n,b_2) =  \{ \{a_n\}, \{a_n,b_2\}\}, \; \cdots, (a_n, b_m) = \{ \{a_n\}, \{a_n,b_m\}\}$$

Is my understanding of these definitions correct?

Comment: Correct. $(a,b)$ is just a short notation.

Comment: But we have that the first component of $(a,b)$ is $a$ and the second one is $b$. See [Ordered pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair) as well as [Hungerford](https://books.google.it/books?id=e-YlBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA6), page 6.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Not clear... What are you trying to say?

Comment: The ordered pair: $(a,b)$ is **defined** as $\{ \{ a \}, \{ a,b \} \}$ Thus, the two symbols name the same thing and they are interchangeable. Of course, the [definieindum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/definiendum) is introduced for better clarity and readibility, and this is why we use it in place of the "more basic" [definiens](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/definiens#English).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, so good. And $A\times B$ is the set which contains all those and nothing else.

**Edit** I see a small mistake in your quoting: The first component isn't $\{a\}$, it's $a$, and the second component is $b$, still without curly brackets.

Comment: Thank you for Answering.

Comment: @Kazi I was a bit quick. See my edit.

Comment: I saw and edited my post appropriately. Thank you for the information!